# fmat not supprted in RcppArmadillo?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to find eigevalues of a very large sparse matrix. I am using RcppArmadillo's eig_gen function which is not specifically for sparse matrices, but I am fine with it as long as the calculations are done with single precision. So my cpp code is:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::cx_fvec getEigenValuesARMASingle(arma::fmat M) {
 return arma::eig_gen(M);
}
```

But I get the following error:

> sourceCpp('EigSingle.cpp')
>   Error in dyn.load("/home/marsha/tmp/Rtmpvko2N0/sourcecpp_9f46104c5262/sourceCpp_1.so") :
>     unable to load shared object '/home/marsha/tmp/Rtmpvko2N0/sourcecpp_9f46104c5262/sourceCpp_1.so':
>     /home/marsha/tmp/Rtmpvko2N0/sourcecpp_9f46104c5262/sourceCpp_1.so: undefined symbol: sgeev_
>   Calls: sourceCpp -> source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> dyn.load
>   Execution halted

Answer (score 1):

R has no support for `float`.  Just use `double` and hence the standard `mat`.